# Circle Class in Java

Tags: java, class, object, awt, collision

Is there an AWT [`Shape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) class for circles?

I want to check for a collision between a rectangle and a circle like I do with 2 [`Rectangles`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) using the `intersects()` method.

Comment: checking that intersection can be rather difficult. 
You can create a class for a circle...

Answer (score 3):

Yes: [`Ellipse2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html).

Mathematically, a circle is a special case of an ellipse where the height and width are the same.
This relationship is the same as the relationship between a square and a rectangle.

There are 2 flavours of `Ellipse2D`; [`Ellipse2D.Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.Float.html) and [`Ellipse2D.Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.Double.html), depending on the precision you want to use.